# How to retrieve assignment, quiz marks from Google Classroom using api in php

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client, google-classroom

I want to read assignments or quiz marks from Google Classroom using API for a project. But I can't find out how to read marks from Google Classroom.

Please give me some suggestions and source code for reading assignments or quiz marks from Google Classroom using PHP or Laravel.

Already I've added some code to the `quickstart.php` file:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
//     throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
// }

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Classroom API & PHP');

    $client->setScopes(array(
        Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_COURSES, 
        Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_STUDENT_SUBMISSIONS_STUDENTS_READONLY, 
        Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_ROSTERS)
      );

    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}

// Copyright 2021 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Classroom($client);

// set these parameters:
// 328776504166 <- It is my course id 
// 339429593407 <- It is my course work id
$courseId = "328776504166";
$courseWorkId = "339429593407";

$results = $service->courses_courseWork_studentSubmissions->listCoursesCourseWorkStudentSubmissions($courseId, $courseWorkId);

foreach ($results->studentSubmissions as $r => $submission) {
    $student = $service->courses_students->get($courseId, $submission->userId);
    $studentName = $student->profile->name->fullName;
    print($studentName . ": ");
    print($submission->assignedGrade. "\n");
}
```

Then when I run `quickstart.php` at localhost the following problems can be seen:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: {
"error": {
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Insufficient Permission",
      "domain": "global",
      "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
    }
  ],
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

}

I can't find my wrong. How to solve this problem? please give me some suggestions

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Please paste your text samples (code, errors, etc) as text, and use the formatting tool (like the answer below). Would you edit your question?

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*You can use the [`courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.list`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/list) method to retrieve a list of student submissions for a piece of coursework. In the response, there will be the `assignedGrade` field.*

#### Example:

```
// Copyright 2021 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Classroom($client);

// set these parameters:
$courseId = "180119025944";
$courseWorkId = "177950380066";

$results = $service->courses_courseWork_studentSubmissions->listCoursesCourseWorkStudentSubmissions($courseId, $courseWorkId);

foreach ($results->studentSubmissions as $r => $submission) {
    $student = $service->courses_students->get($courseId, $submission->userId);
    $studentName = $student->profile->name->fullName;
    print($studentName . ": ");
    print($submission->assignedGrade. "\n");
}
```

Also, make sure that you have the correct scopes set up:

```
$client->setScopes(array(
  Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_COURSES, 
  Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_STUDENT_SUBMISSIONS_STUDENTS_READONLY, 
  Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_ROSTERS)
);
```

#### References:

- [PHP Quickstart | Classroom API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/php)
- [Google Classroom API - PHP Reference](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/classroom/v1/php/latest/index.html)
- [Method: courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.list | Classroom API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/list)

Comment: Hello Rafa Guillermo.

First of all thanks for your valuable suggestion and guideline. Already I've added some code to the quickstart.php file. But when I run quickstart.php at localhost some problems can be seen.  To see the problem please open  this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cQig.png 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlOHd.png
Please tell me Where did I go wrong?

Thank you

Comment: I think it is not in the spirit of Stack Overflow to delete an answer just because it has received a downvote. At 10K rep, you can weather the odd -2! `:=)`

Comment: @Md.Mahmud I've updated my answer; courseId and submission shouldn't have obj references so I've removed them.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Hello .                                                                                                                       I've updated my quickstart.php file according to your suggestion. I've to remove the course Id and submission.  But when I run quickstart.php at localhost some problems can be seen.  To see the code please open this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcVjV.png     To see the problem please open this link :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfQFh.png        Please give me some suggestion and tell Where I made a mistake ?  Thank you  .

Comment: The error is pretty clear, you don’t have the right scopes for what you are trying to do. What scopes do you have? You’re going to need `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students.readonly` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters.readonly` at a minimum based on this snippet, as per the doc pages for [courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.get](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/list) and [courses.students.get](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/get) respectively

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Hello. I've updated my client scopes. But some problems can be seen. To see the client scopes please open this link:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jJe0.png   Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: @Md.Mahmud You do not need all of those scopes. For the methods you are using, you only need the two scopes I mentioned in my previous comment. Why have you copy pasted all of them? You should just use the enumerators. I have updated my answer to show how to include the scopes.

Comment: @Md.Mahmud Also, in future, please copy and paste your code rather than linking screenshots of it, most people will not bother to look into the issue unless it's easy to be able to reproduce

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Thank you very much. I was able to solve my problem according to your  suggestions.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo   Suddenly I can't access any data from google classroom. The above problems appear whenever I want to access data . Please give me some suggestions to solve this problem.